# Cannot execute bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate RuntimeException /vendor/symfony/console/Helper/QuestionHelper.php:129

Tags: symfony4, doctrine-migrations

I am deploying my Symfony 4 app to the production environment for the first time using rsync.

I then try to run the doctrine:migrations:migrate command.

php -v : PHP 5.6.40

CentOS: 7.6

EasyApache4

When I execute:

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

I received the following error:

```
Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in /home/simpleit/ch.simpleitsolutions.bookings/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 85
```

I understand that Symfony 4 DoctrineMigrationsBundle requires PHP 7.1 so I also tried the following:

```
/usr/bin/ea-php71 bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

And I received the following error:

```
WARNING! You are about to execute a database migration that could result in schema changes and data loss. Are you sure you wish to continue? (y/n)[2019-02-10 12:10:52] console.ERROR: Error thrown while running command "{command}". Message: "{message}" {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Aborted at /home/<account_dir>/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/QuestionHelper.php:129)","command":"doctrine:migrations:migrate","message":"Aborted"} []
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup PATH to php bin folder

```
env PATH="/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin:$PATH" bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

Comment: I think I was blindly using the command `/usr/bin/ea-php71 bin/console` which I found elsewhere online and your solution basically points out I was not directly targeting the php (php 7.1) executable.
I can also use `/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

Comment: Error due to the launch of dependent scripts after bin/console with the usual php.

Answer (score 1):

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction --allow-no-migration
```